# How to provide signature for a thin client app?

Tags: encryption, digital-signature, code-signing

If I have a Java thin client app that connects to a server, and I want to protect my client from a malicious use, so I want to implement a sort of signature.

Now the struggle is, if I want to sign the client files, I need to have the keys also on the client side, so if a malicious user wants to alter the client files, even if they are signed he can still alter them and sign them since he can access the keys.

Is my analysis right and what do you suggest?

Comment: Which kind of malicious use do you want to protect yourself against?
Signatures are inherently asymmetric and as such, you do not need to have the signing key client side.

Comment: I mean I want to make sure the attacker does not alter the thin client jars, and do malicous actions. In my case I assume the end user is not trusted . @limeeattack

Comment: The end user would verify the signature on your .jar files using your *public* key.  There are several ways that the user can verify that they have your true and correct public key.  One way is to have a certificate containing your public key signed by a trusted third-party certificate authority.  Another way is through a web of trust model.  Yet another way is for the user to simply download your public key via HTTPS from your site, secured with a certificate signed by a trusted CA.  See https://tails.net/contribute/design/download_verification/ for how Tails does it.

Comment: Check this article: [How to use jarsigner to sign JARs files example](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/jarsigner-digitially-sign-JARs-Java-keytool-certificates). If you still have questions, ask specifically.

Comment: @not2savvy I read this example, so for the jars on client side to be verified by their signature, they only need the certificate file, they don't need the keystore right? (because in screenshot there are both files on client side).
Another thing, with client having access to the certificate, can he manipulate the data ?

Comment: The code is signed with the private key, and only the public key is delivered with the client, which can then be used to verify the signature. Unfortunately, there is a lot of confusion about what exactly a certificate is. A certificate defines what a key can be used for, and often the public key is seen as part of a certificate, but sometimes it's separate. However, that does not make a difference with regard to how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, at least not in a general purpose computing environment.

What you need to do is code your server, so that whatever client is connecting to it, it will act securely.

Comment: can you clarify more ? What do you mean by coding the server ?

Comment: @ethicalhacker - as in write the code the runs the server-side part of the application

Comment: Why shouldn’t it be possible to sign a client application and verify the signature?

Comment: @not2savvy - Any signature verification would be running on the client system, and it would be possible for a malicious user to disable verification and modify the client application. This is a relatively commonly asked thing, maybe this [blog](https://medium.com/@berniedurfee/never-trust-a-client-not-even-your-own-2de342723674) helps explain it better.

Comment: @paj28 There are ways to address the issue you mention, but I'm pretty sure that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @not2savvy - I'm always interested to hear about new ways to secure systems

Comment: @not2savvy - And you've gone quiet. Of course you have, there are no ways to address it

Comment: @paj28 You are right, I misread the question, thinking it is about the client app verifying itself against modifications. I was mislead by the words "I want to protect my client from a malicious use, so I want to implement a sort of signature." Everything changes when we assume a malicious user. Sorry for not reading properly.

Comment: @not2savvy - No problem, and thanks for following up

Comment: @paj28 so there is no way on earth to protect client application from malicous modification ? :)

Comment: @ethicalhacker - Not in a general purpose environment, in a foolproof manner. You can use obfuscation to defeat casual attempts, but a serious hacker can get around that. You can required people to come into your office and use your computers.